# How to sum two columns in sql without group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have columns such as pagecount, convertedpages and changedpages in a table along with many other columns.

pagecount is the sum of convertedpages and changedpages.

I need to select all rows along with pagecount and i cant group them. I am wondering if there is any way to do it?

This select is part of view. so can i use another sql statement to bring just the sum and then somehow make it part of the main sql query?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you share some sample data and a desired result? I'm not sure I understand what you mean by needing to select all rows along with pagecount when you earlier said that pagecount was a part of the table already.

Comment: The column was not used in the front end any more as the users requirements changed. they only enter converted pages and changed pages. but they want to see the combined page count in their report. So i decided to use the column to send the data to the report. (mostly not the smartest design) but it is working now. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
   *,
   (ConvertedPages + ChangedPages) as PageCount
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, while I'm not sure why you can't use `group by`, another option would be to use a `correlated subquery`:

```
select distinct id, 
       (select sum(field) from yourtable y2 where y.id = y2.id) summedresult
from yourtable y
```

---

This assumes you have data such as:

```
id  |  field
1   |  10
1   |  15
2   |  10
```

And would be equivalent to:

```
select id, sum(field)
from yourtable
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% on what you're after here, but if you want a total across rows without grouping, you can use `OVER()` with an aggregate in SQL Server:

```
SELECT *, SUM(convertedpages) OVER() AS convertedpages
     , SUM(changedpages) OVER() AS changedpages
     , SUM(changedpages + convertedpages) OVER() as PageCount
FROM Table
```

This repeats the total for every row, you can use `PARTITION BY` inside `OVER()` if you'd like to have the aggregate to be grouped by some fields while still displaying the full detail of all rows.